# given BlobstoreService served HttpServletResponse, how to fetch the served blob?

Tags: java, android, google-app-engine, servlets, blobstore

Here is my `Serve.java`, which is my Serve `servlet`.

```
public class Serve extends HttpServlet {
private BlobstoreService blobstoreService = BlobstoreServiceFactory.getBlobstoreService();

public void doGet(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse res)
    throws IOException {
        BlobKey blobKey = new BlobKey(req.getParameter("blob-key"));
        blobstoreService.serve(blobKey, res);

    }
}
```

When I host my server and access serve `servlet` via browser, I see my `blob` (a picture). So I'm assuming the `blob`, in its picture file format, is stored in `HttpServletResponse`.

How do I access this `blob` / file? I actually need the file from an `Android` app using `HttpResponse`, but I'll figure that out myself.

Comment: You need to download or you need the URL to your image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a [BlobstoreInputStream](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/javadoc/com/google/appengine/api/blobstore/BlobstoreInputStream)
 to read a blob from the BlobStore programmatically.
If you need the file in an Android app, should serve it the way you already do and just read the response in your app.

Comment: How can I go about reading the response? Do I take the input stream and then make a FileWriter class?

Also, do you know how I can send the blob that's in _res_ and a string as well?

Comment: FileWriter is for writing to files. You have an input stream and you can read it like any other, if you want the Reader interface to read from it you can create a InputStreamReader that wraps it, then if for instance you want to read String lines you can create a BufferedReader instance wrapping it.